# Spacing between nonconsecutive variables

Tags: matlab

I have data set like:

```
101 14.87
104 18.23
110 19.03
113 19.84
```

and want to put it into this form:

```
101 14.87
102
103
104 18.23
105
106
107
108
109
110 19.03
111
112
113 19.84
```

any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first column contains non-repeated integers, you can use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html), which lets you specify the fill value (I'm using `NaN`):

```
result = [(min(A):max(A)).' accumarray(A(:,1)-min(A(:,1))+1, A(:,2), [], @sum, NaN)];
```

Alternatively, you can use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
indices = min(A(:,1)):max(A(:,1));
result = [indices(:) NaN(numel(indices), 1)];
result(ismember(indices, A(:,1) ),2) = A(:,2);
```

Either of the above gives

```
result =

  101.0000   14.8700
  102.0000       NaN
  103.0000       NaN
  104.0000   18.2300
  105.0000       NaN
  106.0000       NaN
  107.0000       NaN
  108.0000       NaN
  109.0000       NaN
  110.0000   19.0300
  111.0000       NaN
  112.0000       NaN
  113.0000   19.8400
```

Comment: I use a software that assumes NaN as zero. How can I just leave them blank?

Comment: @Bob A matrix can't contain blanks. You would need a cell array, such that each cell can contain either a number or an emplty matrix. Is that acceptable for you?

Comment: @Bob Why do you need blanks? Do you need a string-based output?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
x=[101 14.87
104 18.23
110 19.03
113 19.84]

y=(min(x(:,1)):max(x(:,1)))'
y(x(:,1)-min(x(:,1))+1,2)=x(:,2)
```

Note that this assumes integer values in the first column of `x` (otherwise it would not be properly defined what you would want).

You may also want to padd with `NaN` instead of zeros, this can be done by initializing the second column of `y` properly.

Comment: @Bob Blank is not defined inside matrices. You could use a cell array and have an empty matrix there, or an empty string but please confirm whether that is what you need before I try to make it. (Of course you can also try it yourself based on this answer). --- If your software reads `NaN` as 0, you may want to use a trick, like using `Inf`, or `-1` to indicate empty values.